# How to make Blur Effect in backgroundColor React Native 0.61 >

Tags: react-native, blur

in Image Component it is working with blurRadius

```
<Image
   style={styles.img}
   resizeMode='cover'
   source={imgSrc} 
   blurRadius={1}
/>
```

But I want to create blur effect in backgroundColor

Comment: Did you consider using an image of the color (or any flat color image with `tintColor` applied) as a background instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Blur View](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/blur-view/). Works for both Expo Managed Projects as well as Bare Workflows